# Stuck in parsing URL and work with it in a view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inherited-resources

Trying to parse a URL  with this format http://landing.com?data=123 - I'm been able to get the Data through irb like:

```
require "addressable/uri"
uri = Addressable::URI.parse("http://landing.com?data=123")
uri.query_values['data']
=> '123'
```

But I'm stuck on how to interact with that 'data' within a Rails view. I have tried including it in Controller (pages_controller.rb in my sample) like:

```
class PagesController < InheritedResources::Base

  def test
    uri = Addressable::URI.parse("<%= request.original_url %>")
    u = uri.query_values['data']
  end

end
```

But no idea how can I extract that piece of data to be used within my Views. Any guidance on this?

If I open one of the views like where I call that 'test' method - I'm getting *uninitialized constant PagesController::Addressable* but made sure it's in my enviroment with gem which addressable/uri

Comment: could you please mention the rails version you are referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers have a lot of the query information already parsed. You can access it with `params`. In that case, you can use

```
u = params[:data]
```

Comment: So how would you render 'data' in a view/show of one of my Models, if that data does not belong to a Model?

Comment: Use an instance variable. `@u` instead of `u`. Be careful when displaying content of the URL or user generated content. You could create a vulnerability in your app to XSS attacks.

Comment: @SophieDéziel +1 for `XSS` vulnerability alert

Answer (score 0):

As Sophie Déziel said, if it's under an app request, you can access to your query values through params hash. params is present in your controllers and views.

If you are talking about hardcoded URLs or URLS that you get from 3rd party sources, you will nee to create an instance variable in your controller (@u = ...) to be available in your views.

Note that you're not supposed to call action methods in your views, they are 'invoked' by Rails framework.

```
# controller
def my_action
  # .....
  @u = uri.query_values['data']
end

# view
<%= @u %>
```